# For space-qualified electronic components, what is an "SCD"?

Tags: engineering, electronics, specifications, compliance

In terms of engineering documentation for space-qualified electronic components, what is an "SCD"? See, for example, page 6 of this [document](http://www.vectron.com/products/brochures/Vectron_Space_Brochure.pdf).

Is an SCD a common document and does it apply to other (non-electronic) components?

Looking at this particular vendor's [corresponding](http://www.vectron.com/products/space/space.htm) web page, there is a link to their company's generic [SCD](http://www.vectron.com/products/military/xo/os68338.pdf) for the particular component class in question, but it sheds no light on the meaning of the "SCD" abbreviation.

Comment: Space Control Document?  It fits with *"No SCD to write"*..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Specification Control Drawing/Document or Source Control Drawing](http://nepp.nasa.gov/docuploads/FFB52B88-36AE-4378-A05B2C084B5EE2CC/EEE-INST-002_add1.pdf)

page 9:

> Source Control Drawing (SCD) - Provides an engineering description (including configuration, part number, marking, reliability, environmental, functional / performance characteristics), qualification requirements and acceptance criteria for commercial items or vendor developed items procurable from a specialized segment of industry that provides for application critical or unique characteristics.

page 12:

> When parts cannot be procured to Military Specifications, a drawing (such as a Source Control Drawing) should be prepared by the developer to control procurement requirements. The drawing shall include the screening and qualification requirements specified in Tables 2 and 3 of this document for the applicable part type. The drawing shall also include performance parameters, absolute maximum ratings, dimensions, terminal descriptions, materials, and other unique requirements. Existing developer SCDs proposed for use shall be evaluated for compliance to Table 2 and 3 requirements.

Comment: your answer, and more importantly, the reference and its repository is worth a kilo of californium to me. :-)